nextauth 4x credentials sign in - how to append additional db data to user session
I am trying to build a simple credentials sign flow using next-auth ^4.24.5 with nextjs 14 app. My user model has a boolean prop called 'isAdmin' that I would like to expose out to my session using a jwt strategy.
I can see the isAdmin prop as part of the returned user from User.find().
However, I do not see it as part of ANY object returned from any of the callbacks.
This is my config:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import User from "../../../../models/User";

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",

      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Username",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "jsmith@domain.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const user = await User.findOne({
            email: credentials.username,
          }).exec();
          if (user) {
            const isValid = await user.comparePassword(credentials.password);
            if (isValid) return user;
          }

          return null;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return baseUrl;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    signOut: "/auth/signout",
    error: "/auth/error", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // (used for check email message)
    newUser: "/auth/register", // New users will be directed here on first sign in (leave the property out if not of interest)
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


Can anyone spot my issue and shed some light on this? Thank you in advance!

Because you're not finished yet!
There are few things you should do to see what you want;
1) Extend user class
Add a new folder named types at the same level as your auth.ts file. Then add a new file called next-auth.d.ts inside it. Fill it with the code below
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface User {
        id: string
        email: string
        isAdmin: boolean
    }

    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession["user"]
        expires: string
        error: string
    }
}

2) Modify your jwt callback
You should attach isAdmin prop to token
async jwt({ token, user, account, trigger, session }) {
    if (account && user) {
        token.id = user.id
        token.isAdmin = user.isAdmin
        //...
    }
    return token
}

3) Modify your session callback
You should attach isAdmin prop to session from token
async session({ session, token }) {
    return {
        ...session,
        user: {
            ...session.user,
            id: token.id as string,
            isAdmin: token.isAdmin as boolean,
            //...
        },
        error: token.error,
    }
}

That's it! Now you should be able to see it as a separate prop in your session object.
